# react-native-fbsdk get user_birthday and user_location permission doesn't work

Tags: facebook, react-native, permissions, location, fbsdk

Everyone
I am going to get birthday and location from Facebook using react-native-fbsdk.

Here's part of my code:

```
LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'user_birthday', 'user_location'])
        .then((result) => {
          if (result.isCancelled) {
            return;
          }
          AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then((data) => {
              console.log(data); // output 1:
              const responseInfoCallback = (error, profile) => {
                if (error) {
                  console.log(error);
                } else {
                  console.log(profile); // output 2:
                }
              };
              const accessToken = data.accessToken;
              const infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
                '/me',
                {
                  accessToken,
                  parameters: {
                    fields: {
                      string: 'name,gender,birthday,location{location}',
                    },
                  },
                },
                responseInfoCallback,
              );
              new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start();
            });
          });
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

---

```
Here's result of output 1 and 2
--------- output 1 -------
{ accessToken: .......,
          permissions: [ 'email', 'public_profile' ],
          declinedPermissions: [],
          applicationID: '968214779983507',
          accessTokenSource: undefined,
          userID: '161823674419561',
          expirationTime: 1515417067593.333,
          lastRefreshTime: 1510242607593.949 }
-------output 2--------
{ id: '161823674419561', gender: 'male', name: '....' }
```

Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: are you trying as a user with a role in the app?

Comment: @luschn Sorry what do you mean?

Comment: you are testing this with a facebook user. does that user have a role in the app settings? like admin, developer, tester? if you don´t know what i mean, please read about "login review" in the facebook docs.

Comment: @luschn Thanks it's working. If you can give an official answer, I will accept.

Comment: ok, it is done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those permissions only work for users with a role in the App. If you want to make them work for everyone else, you need to go through a review process: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review